Get text from window
How can I get text from window? I'm just starting to learn Python and I want to use it to retrieve the text content of a window. However, I can only get the title. I've tried to retrieve the content through the handle, but I still can't get the text content. Could someone please help me out? Thanks.
import time
import win32gui
import win32con

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    buf = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(255)
    window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    title = win32gui.GetWindowText(window)
    control = win32gui.FindWindowEx(window, 0, 'Edit', None)
    length = win32gui.SendMessage(control, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buf)
    result = buf.tobytes()[:length * 2:2]
    print(result.decode("UTF-8"))
    print('Title: ', win32gui.GetWindowText(window))
    print(str(buf[:length*2], "UTF_8"))

enter image description hereenter image description here
I want to use it to retrieve the text content of a window. I've tried to retrieve the content through the handle, but I still can't get the text content.

Windows applications are generally not a single window. As you have seen the GetWindowText call only returns the title, since that is all the text of the frame. The remaining areas are usually client Windows painted on top of the frame. So you would need to use the EnumChildWindows function, to get to the client control(s). You will then be able to extract the text or other contnet.
